# Что значит \n ?

Tags: php

Есть код :

```
<?php

    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td width='100%' bgcolor='".$TitleBackgroundColour."'><font face='Arial' size='".$TitleSize."'>Error</font></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "<p><font face='Arial' size='".$NormalTextSize."'>".$msg."</font>\n";
    echo "<font face='Arial' size='".$NormalTextSize."'><br>Click <A HREF=JavaScript:history.back()>here</a> to return to the previous page or click the Back button on your browser.</font></p>\n";
    echo "<hr>\n";

?>
```

Что означает \n ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это называется escape последовательность/знак. Применяется в программировании для обозначения невидимых/управляющих символов.

Перечень escape символов [приведен здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4edbef7e.aspx)

**P.S.** В данном случае `\n` это символ новой строки

Answer (score 6):

\n означает перевод на новую строку, НТML код будет отображаться с новой строки, если нажать Ctrl+U (View Source или Просмотр кода HTML).

Answer (score 3):

\n - последовательность символов, сигнализирующая системе о необходимости сделать перенос строки (в unix-подобных системах).
В вашем случае он вывелся из-за неправильного включения в строку.

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере чувак просто добавил \n в каждую строку, видимо не понимая для чего и соответственно смысла это не имеет.
При выводе в браузер для переноса строки пишите <br>
При печати в консоль используйте \n

Comment: Неправда, чувак это сделал не потому, что не знал, а чтобы было удобнее было смотреть на код. Я тоже так часто делаю.

Comment: Ну может наверное так и есть. Я к шаблонизатору привык, так никогда не пишу.